# AngularJS inject data service into controller on version 1.3.8

Tags: angularjs

I'm running a tutorial however they are using a version of AngularJS before 1.3.8.

What am I missing with my code so this data service can be injected?

**They are using the following code to inject a service into a controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Data', function () {
    return { message: "I'm data from a service" };
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
}
```

**Here is my code I am trying to alter so it works:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    return {message:"Data from service"}
});

angular.module('app', Data)
.controller('FirstController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = Data;
}])
.controller('SecondController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {message: "panel"};
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must inject `Data` in the controller @ `.controller('FirstController', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {` not list as module dependency @ `angular.module('app', Data)`. See the [official DI documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for more details and other options.

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('FirstController', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {
   $scope.data = Data;
}])
.controller('SecondController', ['$scope','Data', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = {message: "panel"};
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you fetch a already created module you get by using `angular.module('app')`. You shouldn't be trying to inject the `Data` factory into the module but instead into the controller.

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('FirstController', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {
   $scope.data = Data;
}])
.controller('SecondController', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = {message: "panel"};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('FirstController', ['$scope', function($scope, Data) {
   $scope.data = Data;
}])
.controller('SecondController', ['$scope', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = {message: "panel"};
}]);
```